# Non-linear regression with four parameters

Tags: curves, regression, correlation, data-analysis

Say we have $n$ points; $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),$ and $\dots,(x_n,y_n)$.

Based on least squares, we need to find the best fitting curve that is of the form $$y=a-be^{cx^d}$$

I want to evaluate those parameters in terms of the known $x$'s and $y$'s

For example, linear relation that have the form $y=Sx+I$, we can find $S$ and $I$ as follows:

$$S=\frac{n\sum xy-\sum x \sum y}{n\sum x^2-(\sum x)^2}$$

$$I=\frac{\sum y-S\sum x}{n}$$

> So in the given case (i.e. $y=a-be^{cx^d}$), how to obtain the values
>   of the parameters $a,b,c,$ and $d$ in terms of known $x$'s and $y$'s?

This is probably known as Hockett-Sherby curve.

---

I found a website that calculates these parameters, but I really need to know the theory behind that *parameters calculations*.

---

Any help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Best-fitting in terms of least squares?

Comment: @Alex that is $\sum (y_{actual}-y_{evaluated})^2$ is as small as possible.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari if there is no analytical solution then the website might just calculate the weights numerically

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch thanks for commenting, How can I evaluate those parameters numerically? Please help me. THANKS

Comment: There will be many calculations so it might be easier to leave this to a computer. See for example this implementation in Python: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Thanks dear, I really appreciate what you provide, but I need to know the theory how does computer evaluate $a,b,c,d$ numerically. For calculations, even by solver add-in in excel, the parameters can be calculated. My problem is not to get the values and done, but my problem is to know how. I tried to find in many websites, how does softwares calculate those $a,b,c,d$

Comment: The computer used gradient descent: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent

Answer (score 1):

You want to minimize the sum 
$$
\mathcal{S}=\sum_i^n\Big(y_i-f(x_i;a,b,c,d)\Big)^2
$$ 
with respect to the four parameters, i.e calculate
$$
\nabla \mathcal{S}(a,b,c,d)=\vec{0}.
$$
This will give you four equations to be solved in terms of your four parameters.

For example the first equation you will find is
$$
-2\sum_i^n\Big(y_i-f(x_i;a,b,c,d)\Big)\partial_af=0.
$$